# Ao clicar em um botão, abrir uma box animada

Tags: html5

Tenho uma espécie de botão cujo tem o code:

```
<a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="">EM QUE POSSO AJUDAR?</a>
```

Queria saber como faz para quando eu clicar nela, abrisse uma box a partir do centro da tela, com animação da escala `0%` até a `100%` durante 1 segundo. E com um X no canto superior direito, para caso queira fechar, retornando ao que estava antes de abrir a box. (a estilização da box em CSS eu faço depois, pode ser toda branca mesmo)

Comment: http://kithomepage.com/kit/scripts/janelas/fancybox_inline_ger.php

Comment: Não entendi como faço para isso interagir com o meu botão =/

Comment: <a data-scroll class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" id="exemplo1" href="#inline1" title="EM QUE POSSO AJUDAR?">EM QUE POSSO AJUDAR?</a>